# PHP converting Strings to Arrays back to Strings

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I am pulling data from a query that has the following output:
    1
    2
    3
    5

I am converting it into an array like so:
    `$string = explode("\n", $result);`

I know have an array displaying the following:
`Array
    (
     [0] => 1
     [1] => 2
     [2] => 3
     [3] => 5
    )`

now I am trying to put that array back into a single string having a | seperator

```
    $test = "";    
    foreach($string as $key)
    {
    $test .= $key." | ";
    }
```

however, I am getting the ouput of test:

```
     | 5 |
```

can somone explain why its not showing what I expect it to show and another way how to produce a single string with a | seperator?

thanks

Comment: Unnormalized database // SQL join smell.

Comment: `implode()` is what you want; it does exactly what you're asking for. If you're not seeing that then there's something else going on with your array that you haven't told us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was explode("\r\n", $result) but thanks for showing me the implode function everyone

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
implode("|", $string)
```

Comment: The first element of your array must be an empty string, or a space or something.  What does print_r($string) show?

Comment: Just add spaces to the `" | "` and use `trim()` to take the leading and trailing space off.

Answer (score 7):

`$string = implode(" | ", $result);`

Answer (score 5):

I would think [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) would be what you're looking for.

Also, to comment on why your code is not working, I'm not sure.  Check out this example on ideone.com: http://ideone.com/rH3qbr.  I copied your code and it seems to be working, I think, as you would expect it to.

```
<?php
$result = '1 2 3 4 5';
$string = explode(" ", $result);
$test = "";
foreach($string as $key) {
    $test .= $key." | ";
}
echo $test; // outputs 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 
?>
```

Comment: bozdoz, instead of spaces, they are actually a new line "\n" please try that.

Comment: The link has been updated, but it's the same result. @user1873432

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need the `join`function:
https://www.php.net/join

Answer (score 2):

if $string is the array than you can use implode to convert it into string
Try this

```
$new_string = implode("|", $string);
```

Comment: now I am trying to put that array back into a single string having a | seperator

This is what you asked, you mentioned separator